# getStaticProps/Paths getting "Application Error: A client-side exception has occurred"

Tags: javascript, next.js, sanity

## Explanation

Using this code to fetch a list of products, however I am receiving this error anytime I attempt to load a dynamic `[product].js` route? Can't figure out what is going wrong as I have the same setup for 2 other dynamic routes with the pages being `[photos].js` and `[slug].js` and they load perfectly fine, I have even tried copying the code from those working pages and replacing `album` or `post` with `product` to no avail.

I have double checked my Groq queries with sanity studio vision and they are returning the data that I need.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you, Mac.

## Code

### `[product].js`

```
import sanity from 'sanity';
import DetailsPane from './details';
import ImagesPane from './images';

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const products = await sanity.fetch(`
  *[_type == "product" && !(_id in path("drafts.**"))]{
    slug{
      current
    }
  }
  `);

  return products.map(({ slug }) => ({
    params: { product: slug.current }
  }));
};

export const getStaticProps = async ({ params }) => {
  const product = await sanity.fetch(
    `
  *[slug.current == $product]{
    name, description, category, images, in_stock, options, price, available_in
  }
  `,
    { product: params.product }
  );

  return {
    props: {
      product
    }
  };
};

const Product = ({ product }) => {
  console.log(product);
  return (
    <div className="flex items-center justify-center space-x-4">
      <DetailsPane {...product} />
      <ImagesPane images={product.images} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Product;
```

### Full Error

```
APPLICATION ERROR: A CLIENT-SIDE EXCEPTION HAS OCCURRED (SEE THE BROWSER CONSOLE FOR MORE INFORMATION).
```

### Browser Console

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (logo-tote-bag, line 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## My Bad Really Simple Answer

I have just started using the `pageExtensions` module from next, located [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/custom-page-extensions#including-non-page-files-in-the-pages-directory) and forgot to add `.page.js` to `[product].js`.

Apologies.